# Implement search with date range

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to implement Date range search using Spring Boot. I tried this:

url: `localhost:8080/users/users?page=0&size=3&createdAt=2023-05-02T04:57:19.83795Z`

***Endpoint:***

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/users", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Page<UsersResource> getUsersBySearchSpecification(@Valid UserSearchParams params, Pageable pageable)
    {
        Page<UsersResource> list = userService.getUsersBySpecification(params, pageable);
        return list;
    }
```

***UserSearchParams:***

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class UserSearchParams {

    private String param1;

    private Integer param2;

    private List<String> param3;

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DATE_TIME) 
    LocalDateTime startDate;

    private OffsetDateTime createdAt;
}
```

***Search functionality:***

```
    public Page<Users> getUsersBySpecification(UserSearchParams params, Pageable pageable)
    {
        Specification<Users> spec = (root, query, cb) -> {
            List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();
            if (params.getCreatedAt() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.greaterThan(root.get("createdAt"), params.getCreatedAt()));
            }
            if (params.getCreatedAt() != null) {
                predicates.add(cb.lessThan(root.get("createdAt"), params.getCreatedAt()));
            }
            return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[predicates.size()]));
        };

    return userRepository.findAll(spec, pageable);
}
```

The search functionality is not working. What data type should I use for `createdAt`? `OffsetDateTime` or `LocalDateTime` is better alternative?

Should I manually parse the value `2023-05-02T04:57:19.83795Z` or I can rely on Spring Boot to parse the date?.

Is this code properly implemented:

```
        if (params.getCreatedAt() != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.greaterThan(root.get("createdAt"), params.getCreatedAt()));
        }
        if (params.getCreatedAt() != null) {
            predicates.add(cb.lessThan(root.get("createdAt"), params.getCreatedAt()));
        }
```

Or there is better way to to have this range select?

Comment: what do you mean under "search functionality is not working"? restrictions `cb.lessThan` and `cb.greaterThan` produced by your code are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I mean data is not returned. What should be the proper way to select data range?

Comment: I believe you need to spend some time on redesigning your search API. Typically, when someone wants to find something using range/interval, he provides either both or just one interval boundary, based on that we build corresponding restrictions, in your cause there is no interval at all, so, it is broken by design.

Comment: Ok, I will use 2 variables `createdAtFrom` and `createdAtTo`. What should be the variable type and how to implement interval search into `getUsersBySpecification` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me answer step by ste **based on the experience that I have (multiple different enterprise projects)**. Additional note: I was mostly working with PostgreSQL as a database.

- Usually `LocalDateTime` is used. Because it's a bit more convenient to work with an it has no time-zone info. For databases usually `timestamp` is the appropriate column type.
- Spring Boot is able to parse request parameters to `LocalDateTime` type without explicit custom config implementations. Here is an example of request for `LocalDateTime` type:

  - `https://localhost:8080/my/endpoint?startDate=2023-01-01T00:30:00.000&endDate=2023-12-31T23:30:00.000`
  - `https://localhost:8080/my/endpoint?startDate=2023-01-01T00%3A30%3A00.000&endDate=2023-12-31T23%3A30%3A00.000` (html decoded)

  Here is the appropriate controller code:

```java
    @GetMapping(value = "/my/endpoint")
    public void myMethod(
            @RequestParam(name = "startDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime startDate,
            @RequestParam(name = "endDate") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime endDate) {
        return doSearch(startDate, endDate);
    }
```

But be careful with old Spring versions. From my experience, it should work since Spring Boot 2.2.X. ***The idea is to have an implementation of JPA higher than 2.1 version, because in 2.1 version there is no convenient using of `LocalDateTime`.*** Simply put, use modern versions.

A bit more information can be found [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/whats-new-in-jpa-2-2-java-8-date-and-time-types/).

- As for implementation. Using `LocalDateTime` and JPA implementation 2.2 or higher, your code should work. You can also check code samples here:

  - https://dzone.com/articles/dealing-with-javas-localdatetime-in-jpa
  - [enter link description here](https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl) (it's about `LocalDate`, but should work with `LocalDateTime` too.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you use `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DATE_TIME)`? Is it mandatory?

Comment: I'm using `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DATE_TIME)` to tell Spring how to parse income parameters of `LocalDateTime`. Without the annotation, you will get an exception. A bit more information you can find here: `https://www.baeldung.com/spring-date-parameters`. In the article some other ways of parsing are listed. And also shown the problem of parsing request parameters to `LocalDateTime` without annotations and additional configurations

Comment: I have one additional question: In my case in order to reduce the endpoint code I send a Java Object `UserSearchParams` with search params(See above). Is the annotation code that I added a valid example?

Comment: Yes, should work fine, I've just checked that in my pet project and parameters were parsed successfully